# Woocommerce default Paypal Express plugin Error - [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 9.949999999999999

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I am using the default Paypal Express for woo commerce plugin on my website at dollardecor.com.au, however whenever I try to pay via paypal I get the following error

PayPal error (10427): An error (10427) occurred while processing your PayPal payment. Please contact the store owner for assistance. PayPal error (10413): An error (10413) occurred while processing your PayPal payment. Please contact the store owner for assistance.

On checking the paypal logs I found that though the shipping amount is set up at 9.95, the shipping amount is being passed as 9.949999999999999.

text from the log below.

`[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 19.85 
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 9.9 
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 9.949999999999999`

I have disabled all plugins and checked and couldn't get rid of this error.

Kindly advise.

Thanks.

Comment: That’s just the usual problem with floating point precision ... // Unless there’s a chance this is somehow due to configuration or how exactly you used/integrated the plugin, I’d say you best contact the plugin developer for support.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. This is a default woocommerce plugin. I have contacted the woo commerce support team and will keep this ticket posted in case I find a solution.

Comment: PayPal only accept two decimal point. More than that you'll get an error.